# Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractResource

Tags: extensions, model, methods, construct, abstract-class

**I am getting this error on my homepage after upgrading my Magento version from 2.4.0 to 2.4.6.**

> Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class
> Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractResource in
> /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
> #1 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
> #2 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get()
> #3 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
> #4 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/generated/code/Jes/BannerProductSlider/Model/SliderFactory.php(43):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
> #5 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/app/code/Jes/BannerProductSlider/Helper/Data.php(193):
> Jes\BannerProductSlider\Model\SliderFactory->create()
> #6 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/app/code/Jes/DynamicPages/Block/Pages/HomePage.php(110):
> Jes\BannerProductSlider\Helper\Data->getActiveSliders()
> #7 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/app/code/Jes/DynamicPages/view/frontend/templates/bannerslider.phtml(27):
> Jes\DynamicPages\Block\Pages\HomePage->getActiveSliders()

**I know it is because of the model code. Providing model code of Jes extension**

```
<?php
namespace Jes\BannerProductSlider\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Jes\BannerProductSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\Collection;
use Jes\BannerProductSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
class Slider extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Cache tag
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CACHE_TAG = 'jes_bannerproductslider_slider';

    /**
     * Cache tag
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_cacheTag = 'jes_bannerproductslider_slider';

    /**
     * Event prefix
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'jes_bannerproductslider_slider';

    /**
     * Banner Collection
     *
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $bannerCollection;

    /**
     * Banner Collection Factory
     *
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $bannerCollectionFactory;

     protected $_resourceConnection;

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param CollectionFactory $bannerCollectionFactory
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param AbstractResource $resource
     * @param AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $bannerCollectionFactory,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->bannerCollectionFactory = $bannerCollectionFactory;
        $this->_resourceConnection =$resourceConnection; 
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Jes\BannerProductSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Slider');
    }

    /**
     * Get identities
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    /**
     * get entity default values
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];
        $values['status'] = '1';

        return $values;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    public function getBannersPosition()
    {
        if (!$this->getId()) {
            return [];
        }

        $array = $this->getData('banners_position');
        if ($array === null) {
            $array = $this->getResource()->getBannersPosition($this);
            $this->setData('banners_position', $array);
        }

        return $array;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getSelectedBannersCollection()
    {
        if ($this->bannerCollection === null) {
            $collection = $this->bannerCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->getSelect()->join(
                ['banner_slider' => $this->getResource()->getTable('jes_bannerproductslider_banner_slider')],
                'main_table.banner_id=banner_slider.banner_id AND banner_slider.slider_id=' . $this->getId(),
                ['position']
            );
            $this->bannerCollection = $collection;
        }

        return $this->bannerCollection;
    }
    public function deleteBanners($sliderId)
    {
        $this->_resourceConnection->getConnection()->delete('jes_bannerproductslider_banner_slider',["slider_id ", $sliderId]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional parameter is provided before required.

```
AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
```

Therefore, if ResourceConnection $resourceConnection is a required parameter, it should come before the parameter with the optional value AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null.
Based on this, your constructor should look like the following:

```
public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $bannerCollectionFactory,
    Context $context,
    Registry $registry,
    ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
    AbstractResource $resource = null,
    AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->bannerCollectionFactory = $bannerCollectionFactory;
    $this->_resourceConnection =$resourceConnection; 
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct!